# Cross compiling ROS from source for QNX throws linker error for C 11

Tags: ros, catkin-install, c++11, rospack

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I cross compiled all the third party dependent software for ROS for QNX 7.0 ArmV7. While cross compiling ROS, the linker throws an error linking against the standard c++11 features in the rospack package.

I also tried editing the CMakeLists.txt of rospack to support C++11 but that didnt help

> /opt/qnx/install/arm_catkin_ros/devel_isolated/rospack/lib/librospack.so/opt/qnx/install/arm_catkin_ros/devel_isolated/rospack/lib/librospack.so: warning: : The 'tmpnam' function is dangerous. Use 'mkstemp' instead.warning:
> The 'tmpnam' function is dangerous. Use 'mkstemp' instead.
> /opt/qnx/install/arm_catkin_ros/devel_isolated/rospack/lib/librospack.so: /opt/qnx/install/arm_catkin_ros/devel_isolated/rospack/lib/librospack.sowarning: : The 'tempnam' function is dangerous. Use 'mkstemp' instead.warning:
> The 'tempnam' function is dangerous. Use 'mkstemp' instead.
> /opt/qnx/install/arm_catkin_ros/devel_isolated/rospack/lib/librospack.so: undefined reference to `/opt/qnx/install/arm_catkin_ros/devel_isolated/rospack/lib/librospack.sostd::basic_ios<char, std::char_traits<char> >::init(std::basic_streambuf<char, std::char_traits<char> >*): undefined reference to` '
> std::basic_ios<char, std::char_traits >::init(std::basic_streambuf<char, std::char_traits >*)'
> /opt/qnx/install/arm_catkin_ros/devel_isolated/rospack/lib/librospack.so: undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::_M_replace_aux(unsigned int, unsigned int, unsigned int, char)' /opt/qnx/install/arm_catkin_ros/devel_isolated/rospack/lib/librospack.so: undefined reference to` std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits, std::allocator >::_M_replace_aux(unsigned int, unsigned int, unsigned int, char)'
> /opt/qnx/install/arm_catkin_ros/devel_isolated/rospack/lib/librospack.so: undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<wchar_t, std::char_traits<wchar_t>, std::allocator<wchar_t> >::_M_create(unsigned int&, unsigned int)' /opt/qnx/install/arm_catkin_ros/devel_isolated/rospack/lib/librospack.so: undefined reference to` /opt/qnx/install/arm_catkin_ros/devel_isolated/rospack/lib/librospack.sostd::__cxx11::basic_string<wchar_t, std::char_traits<wchar_t>, std::allocator<wchar_t> >::_M_create(unsigned int&, unsigned int): undefined reference to `' std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::_M_append(char const*, unsigned int)' /opt/qnx/install/arm_catkin_ros/devel_isolated/rospack/lib/librospack.so: undefined reference to` std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits, std::allocator >::_M_append(char const*, unsigned int)'
> /opt/qnx/install/arm_catkin_ros/devel_isolated/rospack/lib/librospack.so: undefined reference to `std::_Rb_tree_decrement(std::_Rb_tree_node_base*)' /opt/qnx/install/arm_catkin_ros/devel_isolated/rospack/lib/librospack.so: undefined reference to` std::ios_base::~ios_base()/opt/qnx/install/arm_catkin_ros/devel_isolated/rospack/lib/librospack.so'
> : undefined reference to `std::_Rb_tree_decrement(std::_Rb_tree_node_base*)' /opt/qnx/install/arm_catkin_ros/devel_isolated/rospack/lib/librospack.so: undefined reference to` /opt/qnx/install/arm_catkin_ros/devel_isolated/rospack/lib/librospack.so: undefined reference to `std::ios_base::~ios_base()std::_Rb_tree_increment(std::_Rb_tree_node_base*)' ' /opt/qnx/install/arm_catkin_ros/devel_isolated/rospack/lib/librospack.so: undefined reference to` /opt/qnx/install/arm_catkin_ros/devel_isolated/rospack/lib/librospack.sostd::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits, std::allocator >::compare(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits, std::allocator > const&) const: undefined reference to `' std::_Rb_tree_increment(std::_Rb_tree_node_base*)' /opt/qnx/install/arm_catkin_ros/devel_isolated/rospack/lib/librospack.so: undefined reference to` std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits, std::allocator >::compare(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits, std::allocator > const&) const'
> /opt/qnx/install/arm_catkin_ros/devel_isolated/rospack/lib/librospack.so: undefined reference to `std::_Rb_tree_increment(std::_Rb_tree_node_base const*)' /opt/qnx/install/arm_catkin_ros/devel_isolated/rospack/lib/librospack.so: undefined reference to` std::_Rb_tree_increment(std::_Rb_tree_node_base const*)'
> /opt/qnx/install/arm_catkin_ros/devel_isolated/rospack/lib/librospack.so: undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::find_last_of(char const*, unsigned int, unsigned int) const' /opt/qnx/install/arm_catkin_ros/devel_isolated/rospack/lib/librospack.so: undefined reference to` /opt/qnx/install/arm_catkin_ros/devel_isolated/rospack/lib/librospack.so: undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::find_last_of(char const*, unsigned int, unsigned int) const' std::codecvt<wchar_t, char, _Mbstatet> const& std::use_facet<std::codecvt<wchar_t, char, _Mbstatet> >(std::locale const&)' /opt/qnx/install/arm_catkin_ros/devel_isolated/rospack/lib/librospack.so/opt/qnx/install/arm_catkin_ros/devel_isolated/rospack/lib/librospack.so: undefined reference to` : undefined reference to `std::ios_base::ios_base()' std::codecvt<wchar_t, char, _Mbstatet> const& std::use_facet<std::codecvt<wchar_t, char, _Mbstatet> >(std::locale const&)' /opt/qnx/install/arm_catkin_ros/devel_isolated/rospack/lib/librospack.so: undefined reference to` /opt/qnx/install/arm_catkin_ros/devel_isolated/rospack/lib/librospack.so: undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::compare(char const*) conststd::ios_base::ios_base()' ' /opt/qnx/install/arm_catkin_ros/devel_isolated/rospack/lib/librospack.so: undefined reference to` /opt/qnx/install/arm_catkin_ros/devel_isolated/rospack/lib/librospack.sostd::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits, std::allocator >::compare(char const*) const: undefined reference to `' vtable for std::basic_ios<char, std::char_traits<char> >' /opt/qnx/install/arm_catkin_ros/devel_isolated/rospack/lib/librospack.so: undefined reference to` std::locale::locale()/opt/qnx/install/arm_catkin_ros/devel_isolated/rospack/lib/librospack.so'
> : undefined reference to `vtable for std::basic_ios<char, std::char_traits<char> >' /opt/qnx/install/arm_catkin_ros/devel_isolated/rospack/lib/librospack.so: undefined reference to` std::locale::locale()'
> /opt/qnx/install/arm_catkin_ros/devel_isolated/rospack/lib/librospack.so: undefined reference to `/opt/qnx/install/arm_catkin_ros/devel_isolated/rospack/lib/librospack.so: undefined reference to` std::codecvt<wchar_t, char, _Mbstatet>::~codecvt()'
> std::codecvt<wchar_t, char, _Mbstatet>::~codecvt()/opt/qnx/install/arm_catkin_ros/devel_isolated/rospack/lib/librospack.so'
> : undefined reference to `/opt/qnx/install/arm_catkin_ros/devel_isolated/rospack/lib/librospack.so: undefined reference to` boost::program_options::validate(boost::any&, std::__1::vector<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits, std::__1::allocator >, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits, std::__1::allocator > > > const&, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits, std::__1::allocator >*, int)'
> boost::program_options::validate(boost::any&, std::__1::vector<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits, std::__1::allocator >, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits, std::__1::allocator > > > const&, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits, std::__1::allocator >*, int)'
> /opt/qnx/install/arm_catkin_ros/devel_isolated/rospack/lib/librospack.so/opt/qnx/install/arm_catkin_ros/devel_isolated/rospack/lib/librospack.so: undefined reference to `: undefined reference to` boost::program_options::abstract_variables_map::operator[](std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits, std::__1::allocator > const&) constboost::program_options::abstract_variables_map::operator[](std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits, std::__1::allocator > const&) const'
> '
> /opt/qnx/install/arm_catkin_ros/devel_isolated/rospack/lib/librospack.so/opt/qnx/install/arm_catkin_ros/devel_isolated/rospack/lib/librospack.so: undefined reference to `: undefined reference to` std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits, std::allocator >::find_first_of(char const*, unsigned int, unsigned int) const'
> std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits, std::allocator >::find_first_of(char const*, unsigned int, unsigned int) const'
> /opt/qnx/install/arm_catkin_ros/devel_isolated/rospack/lib/librospack.so: undefined reference to `/opt/qnx/install/arm_catkin_ros/devel_isolated/rospack/lib/librospack.so: undefined reference to` std::ios_base::Init::~Init()'
> std::ios_base::Init::~Init()'
> /opt/qnx/install/arm_catkin_ros/devel_isolated/rospack/lib/librospack.so: undefined reference to `/opt/qnx/install/arm_catkin_ros/devel_isolated/rospack/lib/librospack.sostd::ostream::put(char): undefined reference to` '
> std::ostream::put(char)'
> /opt/qnx/install/arm_catkin_ros/devel_isolated/rospack/lib/librospack.so: undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::_M_assign(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)/opt/qnx/install/arm_catkin_ros/devel_isolated/rospack/lib/librospack.so' : undefined reference to` std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits, std::allocator >::_M_assign(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits, std::allocator > const&)/opt/qnx/install/arm_catkin_ros/devel_isolated/rospack/lib/librospack.so'
> : undefined reference to `std::logic_error::logic_error(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)' /opt/qnx/install/arm_catkin_ros/devel_isolated/rospack/lib/librospack.so/opt/qnx/install/arm_catkin_ros/devel_isolated/rospack/lib/librospack.so: undefined reference to` : undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::~basic_string()' std::logic_error::logic_error(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)/opt/qnx/install/arm_catkin_ros/devel_isolated/rospack/lib/librospack.so' : undefined reference to` /opt/qnx/install/arm_catkin_ros/devel_isolated/rospack/lib/librospack.sovtable for std::basic_streambuf<char, std::char_traits >: undefined reference to `' std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::~basic_string()' /opt/qnx/install/arm_catkin_ros/devel_isolated/rospack/lib/librospack.so: undefined reference to` vtable for std::basic_streambuf<char, std::char_traits >'
> /opt/qnx/install/arm_catkin_ros/devel_isolated/rospack/lib/librospack.so: undefined reference to `VTT for std::__cxx11::basic_stringstream<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >' /opt/qnx/install/arm_catkin_ros/devel_isolated/rospack/lib/librospack.so: undefined reference to` std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits >& std::__ostream_insert<char, std::char_traits >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits >&, char const*, int)/opt/qnx/install/arm_catkin_ros/devel_isolated/rospack/lib/librospack.so'
> : undefined reference to `VTT for std::__cxx11::basic_stringstream<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >' /opt/qnx/install/arm_catkin_ros/devel_isolated/rospack/lib/librospack.so: undefined reference to` /opt/qnx/install/arm_catkin_ros/devel_isolated/rospack/lib/librospack.sostd::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits >& std::__ostream_insert<char, std::char_traits >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits >&, char const*, int): undefined reference to `' vtable for std::__cxx11::basic_stringbuf<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >' /opt/qnx/install/arm_catkin_ros/devel_isolated/rospack/lib/librospack.so: undefined reference to` std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits, std::allocator >::_M_erase(unsigned int, unsigned int)'
> /opt/qnx/install/arm_catkin_ros/devel_isolated/rospack/lib/librospack.so: undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::reserve(unsigned int)/opt/qnx/install/arm_catkin_ros/devel_isolated/rospack/lib/librospack.so' : undefined reference to` /opt/qnx/install/arm_catkin_ros/devel_isolated/rospack/lib/librospack.sovtable for std::__cxx11::basic_stringbuf<char, std::char_traits, std::allocator >: undefined reference to `' std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::_M_create(unsigned int&, unsigned int)/opt/qnx/install/arm_catkin_ros/devel_isolated/rospack/lib/librospack.so' : undefined reference to` /opt/qnx/install/arm_catkin_ros/devel_isolated/rospack/lib/librospack.sostd::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits, std::allocator >::_M_erase(unsigned int, unsigned int): undefined reference to `' std::runtime_error::runtime_error(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)' /opt/qnx/install/arm_catkin_ros/devel_isolated/rospack/lib/librospack.so: undefined reference to` /opt/qnx/install/arm_catkin_ros/devel_isolated/rospack/lib/librospack.sostd::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits, std::allocator >::reserve(unsigned int): undefined reference to `' std::__cxx11::basic_string<wchar_t, std::char_traits<wchar_t>, std::allocator<wchar_t> >::~basic_string()' /opt/qnx/install/arm_catkin_ros/devel_isolated/rospack/lib/librospack.so: undefined reference to` /opt/qnx/install/arm_catkin_ros/devel_isolated/rospack/lib/librospack.sostd::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits, std::allocator >::_M_create(unsigned int&, unsigned int): undefined reference to `' boost::program_options::options_description::options_description(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, unsigned int, unsigned int)/opt/qnx/install/arm_catkin_ros/devel_isolated/rospack/lib/librospack.so' : undefined reference to` /opt/qnx/install/arm_catkin_ros/devel_isolated/rospack/lib/librospack.so: undefined reference to `std::runtime_error::runtime_error(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::_M_replace(unsigned int, unsigned int, char const*, unsigned int)' ' /opt/qnx/install/arm_catkin_ros/devel_isolated/rospack/lib/librospack.so: undefined reference to` /opt/qnx/install/arm_catkin_ros/devel_isolated/rospack/lib/librospack.sostd::codecvt<wchar_t, char, _Mbstatet>::codecvt(unsigned int): undefined reference to `' std::__cxx11::basic_string<wchar_t, std::char_traits<wchar_t>, std::allocator<wchar_t> >::~basic_string()' /opt/qnx/install/arm_catkin_ros/devel_isolated/rospack/lib/librospack.so: undefined reference to` std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits, std::allocator >::rfind(char, unsigned int) const'
> /opt/qnx/install/arm_catkin_ros/devel_isolated/rospack/lib/librospack.so: undefined reference to `boost::program_options::options_description::options_description(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, unsigned int, unsigned int)' /opt/qnx/install/arm_catkin_ros/devel_isolated/rospack/lib/librospack.so: undefined reference to` std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits, std::allocator >::_M_replace(unsigned int, unsigned int, char const*, unsigned int)'
> /opt/qnx/install/arm_catkin_ros/devel_isolated/rospack/lib/librospack.so: undefined reference to `/opt/qnx/install/arm_catkin_ros/devel_isolated/rospack/lib/librospack.sostd::locale::locale(std::locale const&): undefined reference to` '
> std::codecvt<wchar_t, char, _Mbstatet>::codecvt(unsigned int)'
> /opt/qnx/install/arm_catkin_ros/devel_isolated/rospack/lib/librospack.so/opt/qnx/install/arm_catkin_ros/devel_isolated/rospack/lib/librospack.so: undefined reference to `: undefined reference to` std::locale::locale(char const*)'
> std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits, std::allocator >::rfind(char, unsigned int) const'
> /opt/qnx/install/arm_catkin_ros/devel_isolated/rospack/lib/librospack.so: undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::find(char, unsigned int) const' /opt/qnx/install/arm_catkin_ros/devel_isolated/rospack/lib/librospack.so: undefined reference to` boost::program_options::arg'
> /opt/qnx/install/arm_catkin_ros/devel_isolated/rospack/lib/librospack.so: undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<wchar_t, std::char_traits<wchar_t>, std::allocator<wchar_t> >::_M_replace(unsigned int, unsigned int, wchar_t const*, unsigned int)/opt/qnx/install/arm_catkin_ros/devel_isolated/rospack/lib/librospack.so' : undefined reference to` /opt/qnx/install/arm_catkin_ros/devel_isolated/rospack/lib/librospack.so: undefined reference to `std::locale::locale(std::locale const&)' boost::program_options::to_internal(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&)' /opt/qnx/install/arm_catkin_ros/devel_isolated/rospack/lib/librospack.so/opt/qnx/install/arm_catkin_ros/devel_isolated/rospack/lib/librospack.so: undefined reference to` : undefined reference to `std::locale::~locale()std::locale::locale(char const*)' ' /opt/qnx/install/arm_catkin_ros/devel_isolated/rospack/lib/librospack.so: undefined reference to` /opt/qnx/install/arm_catkin_ros/devel_isolated/rospack/lib/librospack.so: undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::find(char, unsigned int) const' boost::program_options::detail::cmdline::cmdline(std::__1::vector<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > > > const&)' /opt/qnx/install/arm_catkin_ros/devel_isolated/rospack/lib/librospack.so/opt/qnx/install/arm_catkin_ros/devel_isolated/rospack/lib/librospack.so: undefined reference to` : undefined reference to `boost::program_options::argstd::ios_base::Init::Init()' ' /opt/qnx/install/arm_catkin_ros/devel_isolated/rospack/lib/librospack.so: undefined reference to` std::__cxx11::basic_string<wchar_t, std::char_traits<wchar_t>, std::allocator<wchar_t> >::_M_replace(unsigned int, unsigned int, wchar_t const*, unsigned int)'
> /opt/qnx/install/arm_catkin_ros/devel_isolated/rospack/lib/librospack.so: undefined reference to `/opt/qnx/install/arm_catkin_ros/devel_isolated/rospack/lib/librospack.so: undefined reference to` boost::program_options::to_internal(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits, std::__1::allocator > const&)typeinfo for std::codecvt<wchar_t, char, _Mbstatet>'
> '
> /opt/qnx/install/arm_catkin_ros/devel_isolated/rospack/lib/librospack.so/opt/qnx/install/arm_catkin_ros/devel_isolated/rospack/lib/librospack.so: undefined reference to `: undefined reference to` std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits, std::allocator >::_M_mutate(unsigned int, unsigned int, char const*, unsigned int)std::locale::~locale()'
> '
> /opt/qnx/install/arm_catkin_ros/devel_isolated/rospack/lib/librospack.so: undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::swap(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >&)' /opt/qnx/install/arm_catkin_ros/devel_isolated/rospack/lib/librospack.so: undefined reference to` boost::program_options::detail::cmdline::cmdline(std::__1::vector<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits, std::__1::allocator >, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits, std::__1::allocator > > > const&)'
> /opt/qnx/install/arm_catkin_ros/devel_isolated/rospack/lib/librospack.so: undefined reference to `std::__throw_out_of_range_fmt(char const*, ...)/opt/qnx/install/arm_catkin_ros/devel_isolated/rospack/lib/librospack.so' : undefined reference to` std::ios_base::Init::Init()'
> /opt/qnx/install/arm_catkin_ros/devel_isolated/rospack/lib/librospack.so: undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::find_first_not_of(char const*, unsigned int, unsigned int) const' /opt/qnx/install/arm_catkin_ros/devel_isolated/rospack/lib/librospack.so: undefined reference to` typeinfo for std::codecvt<wchar_t, char, _Mbstatet>'
> /opt/qnx/install/arm_catkin_ros/devel_isolated/rospack/lib/librospack.so: undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::_M_mutate(unsigned int, unsigned int, char const*, unsigned int)/opt/qnx/install/arm_catkin_ros/devel_isolated/rospack/lib/librospack.so' : undefined reference to` /opt/qnx/install/arm_catkin_ros/devel_isolated/rospack/lib/librospack.soboost::program_options::value_semantic_codecvt_helper::parse(boost::any&, std::__1::vector<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits, std::__1::allocator >, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits, std::__1::allocator > > > const&, bool) const: undefined reference to `' std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::swap(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >&)/opt/qnx/install/arm_catkin_ros/devel_isolated/rospack/lib/librospack.so' : undefined reference to` vtable for std::__cxx11::basic_stringstream<char, std::char_traits, std::allocator >'
> /opt/qnx/install/arm_catkin_ros/devel_isolated/rospack/lib/librospack.so/opt/qnx/install/arm_catkin_ros/devel_isolated/rospack/lib/librospack.so: undefined reference to `: undefined reference to` std::__throw_out_of_range_fmt(char const*, ...)std::__throw_length_error(char const*)'
> '
> /opt/qnx/install/arm_catkin_ros/devel_isolated/rospack/lib/librospack.so: undefined reference to `/opt/qnx/install/arm_catkin_ros/devel_isolated/rospack/lib/librospack.sostd::__cxx11::basic_string<wchar_t, std::char_traits<wchar_t>, std::allocator<wchar_t> >::compare(wchar_t const*) const: undefined reference to` '
> std::_*cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits, std::allocator >::find_first_not_of(char const*, unsigned int, unsigned int) const/opt/qnx/install/arm_catkin_ros/devel_isolated/rospack/lib/librospack.so'
> : undefined reference to `std::_Rb_tree_insert_and_rebalance(bool, std::_Rb_tree_node_base*, std::_Rb_tree_node_base*, std::_Rb_tree_node_base&)' /opt/qnx/install/arm_catkin_ros/devel_isolated/rospack/lib/librospack.so: undefined reference to` TiXmlString::nullrep*'
> /opt/qnx/install/arm_catkin_ros/devel_isolated/rospack/lib/librospack.so: undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_stringstream<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::~basic_stringstream()' /opt/qnx/install/arm_catkin_ros/devel_isolated/rospack/lib/librospack.so: undefined reference to` /opt/qnx/install/arm_catkin_ros/devel_isolated/rospack/lib/librospack.so: undefined reference to `std::locale::operator=(std::locale const&)' boost::program_options::value_semantic_codecvt_helper<char>::parse(boost::any&, std::__1::vector<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > > > const&, bool) const' /opt/qnx/install/arm_catkin_ros/devel_isolated/rospack/lib/librospack.so/opt/qnx/install/arm_catkin_ros/devel_isolated/rospack/lib/librospack.so: undefined reference to` : undefined reference to `vtable for std::__cxx11::basic_stringstream<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::find(char const*, unsigned int, unsigned int) const' ' /opt/qnx/install/arm_catkin_ros/devel_isolated/rospack/lib/librospack.so: undefined reference to` /opt/qnx/install/arm_catkin_ros/devel_isolated/rospack/lib/librospack.sostd::__throw_logic_error(char const*): undefined reference to `' std::__throw_length_error(char const*)' /opt/qnx/install/arm_catkin_ros/devel_isolated/rospack/lib/librospack.so: undefined reference to` std::_*cxx11::basic_string<wchar_t, std::char_traits<wchar_t>, std::allocator<wchar_t> >::compare(wchar_t const*) const'
> cc: /opt/qnx/install/host/linux/x86_64/usr/bin/arm-unknown-nto-qnx7.0.0eabi-ld error 1
> /opt/qnx/install/arm_catkin_ros/devel_isolated/rospack/lib/librospack.so: undefined reference to `std::_Rb_tree_insert_and_rebalance(bool, std::_Rb_tree_node_base*, std::_Rb_tree_node_base*, std::_Rb_tree_node_base&)' /opt/qnx/install/arm_catkin_ros/devel_isolated/rospack/lib/librospack.so: undefined reference to` TiXmlString::nullrep*'
> /opt/qnx/install/arm_catkin_ros/devel_isolated/rospack/lib/librospack.so: undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_stringstream<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::~basic_stringstream()' /opt/qnx/install/arm_catkin_ros/devel_isolated/rospack/lib/librospack.so: undefined reference to` std::locale::operator=(std::locale const&)'
> /opt/qnx/install/arm_catkin_ros/devel_isolated/rospack/lib/librospack.so: undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::find(char const*, unsigned int, unsigned int) const' /opt/qnx/install/arm_catkin_ros/devel_isolated/rospack/lib/librospack.so: undefined reference to` std::__throw_logic_error(char const*)'
> cc: /opt/qnx/install/host/linux/x86_64/usr/bin/arm-unknown-nto-qnx7.0.0eabi-ld error 1
> CMakeFiles/rospackexe.dir/build.make:103: recipe for target '/opt/qnx/install/arm_catkin_ros/devel_isolated/rospack/bin/rospack' failed
> make[2]: *** [/opt/qnx/install/arm_catkin_ros/devel_isolated/rospack/bin/rospack] Error 1
> CMakeFiles/Makefile2:264: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/rospackexe.dir/all' failed
> make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/rospackexe.dir/all] Error 2
> make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
> CMakeFiles/rosstackexe.dir/build.make:103: recipe for target '/opt/qnx/install/arm_catkin_ros/devel_isolated/rospack/bin/rosstack' failed
> make[2]: *** [/opt/qnx/install/arm_catkin_ros/devel_isolated/rospack/bin/rosstack] Error 1
> CMakeFiles/Makefile2:227: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/rosstackexe.dir/all' failed
> make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/rosstackexe.dir/all] Error 2
> Makefile:138: recipe for target 'all' failed
> make: *** [all] Error 2
> <== Failed to process package 'rospack':
> Command '['/opt/qnx/install/arm_catkin_ros/devel_isolated/rosmaster/env.sh', 'make', '-j8', '-l8']' returned non-zero exit status 2

EDIT:

The qnx toolchain file is

cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5.1)

set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME QNX)
set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_VERSION 7.0.0)
set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR armv7)
set(TOOLCHAIN QNX)

message(STATUS "QNX_HOST: $ENV{QNX_HOST}")
message(STATUS "QNX_TARGET: $ENV{QNX_TARGET}")
message(STATUS "CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME-CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR: ${CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME}-${CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR}")

if ("$ENV{QNX_HOST}" STREQUAL "")
message(FATAL_ERROR "Wrong or missing QNX_HOST environment variable, forgot to source /opt/qnx/700/qnxsdp-env.sh ?")
endif()

if ("$ENV{QNX_TARGET}" STREQUAL "")
message(FATAL_ERROR "Wrong or missing QNX_TARGET environment variable, forgot to source /opt/qnx/700/qnxsdp-env.sh ?")
endif()

find_path(QNX_HOST
NAME usr/bin/qcc${HOST_EXECUTABLE_SUFFIX}
PATHS $ENV{QNX_HOST}
NO_CMAKE_PATH
NO_CMAKE_ENVIRONMENT_PATH
)

find_path(QNX_TARGET
NAMES usr/include/qnx_errno.h usr/include/errno.h
PATHS $ENV{QNX_TARGET}
NO_CMAKE_PATH
NO_CMAKE_ENVIRONMENT_PATH
)

set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH
$ENV{QNX_TARGET}/${CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR}
$ENV{QNX_TARGET}
$ENV{QNX_TARGET}/armle-v7/
$ENV{QNX_TARGET}
)
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH $ENV{QNX_TARGET}/armle-v7 $ENV{QNX_TARGET})
set(BOOST_ROOT /home/hari1234/qnx_cross_compile/src/arm/boost_1_64_0/build)
set(TinyXML_ROOT_DIR /home/hari1234/qnx_cross_compile/src/arm/tinyxml/cmake_build)
set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER qcc)
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER QCC)

set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER_TARGET gcc_ntoarmv7le)
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_TARGET gcc_ntoarmv7le_cxx)
set(CMAKE_STRIP "${QNX_HOST}/usr/bin/nto${CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR}-strip${HOST_EXECUTABLE_SUFFIX}" CACHE PATH "QNX Strip Program")

add_definitions("-D__EXT")

The error also shows the issue is with Boost::Program_options. I checked in the CMakeLists.txt of rospack and it seems that it is linking against the locally cross compiled static library of Boost::program_options

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/264528/cross-compiling-ros-from-source-for-qnx-throws-linker-error-for-c--11/) by [mhariharasudan](https://answers.ros.org/users/3407/mhariharasudan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 70 on 2017-06-22

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [cdtdoug](https://answers.ros.org/users/30867/cdtdoug/) on 2017-06-22**:
Can you share the CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE you're using for QNX?

**Comment by [mhariharasudan](https://answers.ros.org/users/3407/mhariharasudan/) on 2017-06-22**:
I have added the toolchain file for your reference

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-06-22**:
@mhariharasudan: in the future: please use the *Preformatted Text* button (the one with `101010` on it) instead of the block quote for console and code copy-pastes. It works much better.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I did not get this error when I compiled my boost libraries as dynamic instead of static

---

Originally posted by [mhariharasudan](https://answers.ros.org/users/3407/mhariharasudan/) with karma: 70 on 2017-06-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0